# How to layout widgets in tkinter while using the Zoomed state + frames

Tags: python, tkinter

How would i go on about placeing widgets on a frame, which is in the zoomed state, that cannot be resized while using `.grid()`?

I want to be able to place the buttons on the right most of the screen while placing a treeview on the left of the screen, with say an instance of 'whitespace' in the middle. I'm not sure if it can be done personally, and in my experience with tkinter i have only used smaller windows which are not 'Zoomed' or 'fullscreen' making `.grid()` placement really easy to use without this problem. Ive looked across the web for a solution but not yet found one.

I would like to be able to layout my tkinter window in the layout provided down below.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The frustrating thing about questions like this is a) there are at least half a dozen ways to accomplish what you want, and b) the best way depends on variables that you haven't defined. For example, how do you decide the proportions of each section -- are you hard-coding them, do you want tkinter to compute them based on what's inside? What behavior do you want if the user resizes the window? And so on.

### Getting Started

Let's start with the import statements and the root window. I hate full screen windows so I'm going with a smaller fixed size. The layout will work no matter what size, you can resize it to whatever you want.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("900x600")
```

### Add frames for each section

Next, lets create a frame for each section. Each frame will use the colors from your image to make it easier to visualize. I could use any widget, but frames are the most common widget to use as a container for other widgets (for example, a treeview or text widget with a scrollbar, a graph possibly with buttons, etc)

```
treeview_frame = tk.Frame(root, background="#FFF0C1", bd=1, relief="sunken")
graph_frame = tk.Frame(root, background="#D2E2FB", bd=1, relief="sunken")
text_frame = tk.Frame(root, background="#CCE4CA", bd=1, relief="sunken")
button_frame = tk.Frame(root, background="#F5C2C1", bd=1, relief="sunken")
```

### Designing your layout

With that out of the way, we can lay the widgets out. We could use `pack` for this pretty easily, but `grid` can be a bit easier to understand when you're learning.

When I look at your image, it's pretty clear to me that you have two rows and three columns. It looks like the first column (column 0) is a smidge wider than the other columns. Similarly, the first row (row 0) looks to be a smidge taller than the other row. We'll use that information in a bit.

### Laying out the widgets with grid

First, let's put everything in their respective rows and columns. It should be pretty obvious, so I'll let the code do the explaining.

```
treeview_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
graph_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
text_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
button_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
```

## Configuring the grid as a whole

Next comes a very important step that almost all beginners forget: you need to give each row and column a weight. The weight determines how `grid` allocates extra space. Since you said you want a zoomed window, you'll probably have a bunch of extra space after adding in your actual widgets.

Here's where the relative widths and heights come in. The `weight` attribute is a value that specifies how extra space is allocated. For example, if you have a column with a weight of 1 (one), and another with a weight of 2, the one with the weight of 2 will get two times the extra space of the other. In For example, if tkinter calculates that there's 100 extra pixels it needs to fill, it will give 66 or 67 pixels to one, and 33 or 34 to the other.

Something to keep in mind is that rows and columns have a weight of 0 (zero). That means that they are not given any extra space.

A rule of thumb says that most of the weight should be given to the "main" widget on the screen. For a text editor that would be a text widget, for a drawing app it might be a canvas. For a reporting app it might be a treeview. Since you have all of that, I don't know exactly how you want the space allocated.

#### Configuring the rows

I'm going to guess, and say that row 0 where the treeview is should take up a little more than half the height. I'm going to give it a weight of 3 and the other a weight of 2. If you want both the treeview and graph to be the same size you would give them each a weight of 1. If the graph is a fixed size but the treeview should be as big as possible, give the graph a weight of 0 (zero) and the tree a weight of 1.

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=3)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=2)
```

#### Configuring the columns

Now we need to go through the same exercise with the columns. It looks like the first column, column zero, takes up just a bit more room than the other columns. So, I'm going to give it a weight of 3 and the others a weight of 2. Like with the rows, you can put all the weight in one column, distribute it equally, or do it however you wish.

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=2)
```

### Final steps

That's it, for a basic layout.

If you call a call to `root.mainloop()` at the end of all that code you'll have a window that looks almost exactly like the picture you provided. Notice that it all scales beautifully as you resize the window.

### Adding more widgets

Now you can start to add widgets to each frame, without having to worry too much about how they affect the rest of the window. Not only that, but you can use `pack` for some, and `grid` or `place` for others. For example, if you wanted the treeview to have a scrollbar, you might create it like this:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(treeview_frame)
sb = ttk.Scrollbar(treeview_frame)
sb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
tree.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

The only thing that might surprise you is that if you put in a very large widget, it may mess up the proportions. The simplest solution is usually to set the width and  height to something small, and let it grow to fit. If you make it large, it will want to be large, pushing other widgets away.